# Surjective functions with Kernel T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets say I have a linear transformation $T$ from $R^3$ to $R^3$ and we have a kernel not equal to zero.

How can we Identify if this is injective, surjective, and bijective.

Injective: If the kernel is not equal to zero then that means that for our range/Image we have dimension 2. Then this will fail to be injective as going from dimension 3 to dimension 2 values will not be one to one.

Surjective: (I need clarification on this)

Bijective: due to injectivity failing this fails automatically.

How can I determine if the function is surjective?

I believe surjectivity means that every input will have an output not necessarily 1 to 1. Going From inputs in $R^3$ to outputs in $R^2$ I do not see a problem. Can I therefore say this transformation will be surjective?

Comment: "*If the kernel is not equal to zero then that means our range/image we have dimension 2*"  Incorrect.  Our range will be dimension *at most* two in this case.  For the general case of going from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ where $n$ and $m$ are possibly different, you'll have more specific results, but for the case where $n=m$ very simply a linear transformation is injective iff it is bijective iff it is surjective iff it has trivial kernel, and several other equivalent statements.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Answer (score 3):

**Injectivity:** Since $\ker T\neq\{0\}$, there is some $v\in\ker T\setminus\{0\}$. Then $v\neq0$, but $T(v)=T(0)=0$. Therefore, $T$ is not injective.

**Surjectivity:** By the rank-nullity theorem,$$\dim T(\mathbb R^3)=3-\dim\ker T<3=\dim\mathbb R^3.$$So, $T$ is not surjective.